# Compiling html templates using handlebars.js in backbone marionette CollectionView

Tags: jquery, html, marionette, collectionview, handlebars.js

I am using backbone marionette with handlebars.js and require.js. So I know how to use templates if we don't have to supply anty dynamic value.

But now I have to show a list of employees using CollectionView of marionette framework So now I am not able to understand how to use handlebar to supply dynamic data into Collection View.

This is my view

```
ContactManager.module('ContactsApp.List', function(List, ContactManager,
        Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    List.Contact = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName : "li",
        template : Handlebars.compile(EmployeeTemplate)
    });

    List.Contacts = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName : "ul",
        itemView : List.Contact
    });
});
```

This is the template

```
<label><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %> </label>
```

How to supply these parameters dynamically to the CollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Marionette documentation for the Renderer and TemplateCache. Between these two resources, you should be able to do this. I use Mustache personally, and overrode the methods specified in the documentation...and it works GREAT.

#### First the Renderer:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.renderer.md#custom-template-selection-and-rendering

Basically, override the `Renderer.render method`. It will receive the template id (what you specify on your model, and the data). It should return the rendered template.

#### And then the TemplateCache:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.templatecache.md#customizing-template-access

The TemplateCache can be used to both retrieve the template, via `loadTemplate` and then compile the template with `compileTemplate`. Override these to point to Handlebars, and away you go!

Hope this helps!